# SonarQube Custom rules missing when restoring xml plugin quality profile

Tags: sonarqube, profiles

I have the Sonar XML Plugin installed and we have a custom xml file with pre-defined rules. When restoring the profile by referencing the xml file, sonar does not import the custom rules and instead shows a "Rule not found:" error. The only rules imported appear to be three default rules (indent, newline, etc..). Within the restored profile I can create custom rules from the xpath_rule template and create another backup of the profile. Then I am able to delete/restore the profile referencing the new backed up xml file generated by sonar and it will import all of the rules correctly.

However, if I uninstall the xml plugin or perform a fresh install of sonar and attempt to restore the profile it again does not import the custom rules and only displays the three default rules despite the referenced backup file having been generated by sonar during the backup process.

I have tested this on 3.7.4, 4.0, 4.1.2, 4.2, 4.5.4 and 5.1 with the same results across the board. When researching this issue, I've only seen posts from a year ago with no resolution.

The idea is to have one xml file which all of our developers can restore from to import the latest rules. Any help would be appreciated.